# VS2012 Express Textbox missing KeyPress event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, visual-studio-express

Been searching this for a while now.

Want to be able to trigger the KeyPress event of my Textbox, but I'm not able to.
I've been searching for a while now, saw things as 'add system.windows.forms dll'.. So I added to the top of my page:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

But still the same error..'

I'm working here with 'Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web' and I'm creating a normal aspx-website. Is this not possible here to trigger that event or am I missing something?

I'm able to trigger the 'textchanged' event, but that's not what I'm looking for because that seems only to trigger my function when the textbox lost the focus..

[image]

A little help here please..

Comment: if you are creating a website, the control is from  `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControls`.  If you open the object browser and find it, you'll see the Web version does not support the keypress event.  your import means nothing, because the control is from the namespace above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no KeyPress event when you're working with an ASP.NET program. If you look at the articles returned from https://www.google.com/#q=asp.net+keypress+event+textbox then you will see that they use JavaScript on the client.

Depending on why you want to intercept every keypress, you may be able to implement the desired functionality in JavaScript. You *could* use AJAX to send a message to the server every time a key is pressed, but the user experience of relatively slow typing or things happening out of sync with what they are typing could be undesirable.

You should remove the reference to System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: I want to add an autocomplete function based on the typed value in the textbox. This function will call a stored procedure and will get the best matching autocomplete answer on the typed word. Everytime the user types an extra letter this function needs to be triggered. The textbox is located at my masterpage so there's no possibilty to call a pagemethod with jquery as well.. So here I'm in doubt how to do it the best way

Comment: Your research could be aided by searching for "jquery autocomplete from database ashx example". You will need to write some sort of web handler to return appropriate data.

Comment: Thx for the response Andrew, will check this out within 24hours, if this helps me out, I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You want the [TextChaned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-%20us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event and make sure to also set the [AutoPostback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property on the text box to True for this to work.

KeyPress is a WinForms event and VS2012 Express for Web won't even have the references for WinForms classes. Remove the KeyPress usage altogether.